# Why is this function $h(x)$ invalid?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic

Let there be two functions, $f(x,y)$ and $g(x)$, such that
$$f:\Bbb{R} \times \Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$$
$$g:\Bbb{R} \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$$
Our initial set is $\{0\}$. If we define the functions like this
$$f(x,y)=x \cdot y$$
$$g(x)=x+1$$
we can use them to generate $\Bbb{N_0}$ from $\{0\}$ (mathematical induction).

---

Now, lets create function $h(x)$ such that it maps
$$\Bbb{N_0} \rightarrow S$$
where $S$ is set.
Now, why is the function $h(x)$ defined like this invalid?
$$h(0)=0$$
$$h(f(x,y))=f(h(x),h(y))$$
$$h(g(x))=h(x)+2$$
As you can see, I'm trying to use $h(x)$ (which is a recursive function) to generate $S$ from $\Bbb{N_0}$.
I know that these rules are somehow contradicting each other, but I don't know how. That's my question: why are these rules contradicting each other?

---

This problem is taken from the book [*A Mathematical Introduction To Logic [2nd edition]*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/250872.A_Mathematical_Introduction_to_Logic?from_search=true) (p. 38) by [Herbert Enderton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbert_Enderton). This problem is not "copy-pasted" from the book, so I screenshotted it for those of you who want to see the original. You can see it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI1rg.jpg).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show that the function $h$ you're constructing is in fact well-defined: I can't allow the rules I've set up to contradict each other.

For example, consider $h(6)$.

- On the one hand, $6=f(2, 3)$ so we need to have $h(6)=h(2)h(3)$.
- On the other hand, $6=g(5)$ so we need to have $h(6)=h(5)+2$.
- On the other other hand, $6=f(1, 6)$ so we need to have $h(6)=h(1)h(6)$.

So in order for our rules to make sense, we'd better have $$h(5)+2=h(2)h(3)=h(1)h(6).$$ My point isn't that this is obviously *false*, but rather obviously *worrying*: we now need to prove, somehow, that we're never going to be able to apply the rules you've provided to produce contradictory results.

Towards actually *showing* that these rules lead to contradictory facts about $h$, it's a good idea to start by thinking about what you can say about the values of $h(0)$ and $h(1)$ ...

Comment: So, the contradiction is in that $h(x)$ maps in one-to-many relationship? In other words, $h(x)$ can have multiple outputs and that is what is problematic?

Comment: @Vuk: The contradiction is that there is no function at all that satisfies all the conditions you claim your $h$ should satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

From the 1st and 3rd defining equations show $h(1) = 2$.
From the 2nd defining equation using $x = y = 1$, $h(1) = 4$.